# Which are the minimum API requirements of the compatibility package?

Tags: android, package, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I know the Compatibility Package is very useful and provides backward compatibility. One thing i am not sure, will all the libraries in the package can be used on all version of Android let say above 2.1.

Comment: Read the docs... it's a second away in Google. But just in case, read answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: The Support Package includes more than one support library. Each one has a different minimum API level. For example, one library requires API level 4 or higher, while another requires API level 13 or higher (v13 is a superset of v4 and includes additional support classes to work with v13 APIs). The minimum version is indicated by the directory name, such as v4/ and v13/.

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

To support 2.1, use compatibility library "v4".

Comment: And obviously, you'll be limited to what the v4 provides.